# JIRA Add comment after update status

Tags: jira

I`m using JIRA and have this question:
Perhaps someone can tell me other ways how to add comment after the post-status updates?

Comment: Are you referring to post functions in a workflow transition. By default a post function is added to all transitions to add any comment added during the transition. Or do you mean adding a comment in some other way?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to edit your JIRA workflow to achieve this. You can add a validator to the transitions for which you want to make comments mandatory.

```
Under Validator -> Add -> Comment Required Validator -> Enter an error message and set any exemptions -> Add
```

Here is a link on [Atlassian Answers](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/30446/comment-field-as-a-mandatory-one-when-resolving-an-issue).